# Crear archivo environment en ionic personalizado

Tags: ionic4, ionic-framework

Estoy haciendo una app con ionic, y por defecto al generar el proyecto se generan dos archivos de ambiente, el environment.ts y el environment.prod.ts.
Si ejecuto ionic serve, la app se ejecuta en el navegador usando el archivo environment.ts, y si ejecuto ionic serve --prod usa el .prod.ts.
Mi pregunta es como puedo crear otro archivo environment.test.ts y ejecutar ionic serve --test y que use este archivo?
Cree el archivo, pensando que eso bastaría pero no, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Según [la documentación](https://angular.io/guide/build) deberías añadir **test** en el archivo de configuración `angular.json`:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": { ... },
  "test": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Además un poco por debajo, en `serve` deberás añadir:

```
"serve": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
     "production":{...},
     "test": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build:test"
      },

   }
}
```

Luego debería funcionar usando:

```
ionic serve --configuration=test
```

Comment: hay alguna manera de imprimir en consola si realmente estoy usando ese env?